# Python: I can import packages in python but not in the notebook

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed two packages such as [mgwr](https://mgwr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [libpysal](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libpysal).

I can import them using a normal python script but when I try to import in my jupyter notebook I get the error that the modules don't exist

```
import libpysal as ps
ImportError: No module named libpysal

from mgwr.gwr import GWR, MGWR
ImportError: No module named mgwr
```

if I do from Terminal

```
! which python 
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
```

from the notebook

```
! which python
/Users/myName/anaconda2/bin/python
```

Comment: Is your notebook using the same install of Python as your running your .pys with?

Comment: To check, try `! which python` in Jupyter and check that the output is the same as `which python` in the terminal where you run your script.

Comment: @BHC I added it in the question

Comment: whats the output of `echo $PATH` in terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to get your system to look for the anaconda version of Python by telling it where it's located.

```
cd ~
nano .bashrc
```

Now add `export PATH="/home/<myName>/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"` to the end of the file.

You can now refresh the `PATH` variable by using `source` or `.`

```
. .bashrc
```

Hopefully `which python` now points to your anaconda folder. If it does, go ahead and `conda install` the packages that Jupyter isn't finding. If not, leave a comment.

Comment: I thing that I did not understand how to do it. The file `.baschrc` is empty

Comment: Did you spell it right or was that just a typo in your comment? Should be `.bashrc`. If you did, did you change to your home directory (`cd ~`)? And can you send the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Did it. Thank you